# How to use PowerShell Where-Object to return TFS changesets that have no workitems assigned?

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have the following PowerShell command to retrieve TFS changesets with associated workitems:

```
Get-TfsItemHistory "$/path" -Version "D01/12/10~" -Recursive 
  | Select ChangesetId -exp WorkItems 
  | Format-Table ChangesetId, Id, Title -Auto
```

However, I also need to see changesets that have no assigned workitem.  I imagined I could do the following (modified as per suggestion below):

```
Get-TfsItemHistory "$/path" -Version "D01/12/10~" -Recursive 
  | Select ChangesetId -exp WorkItems 
  | Where-Object {$_.WorkItems -eq $null }
```

However this seems to ignore my where clause and returns the same list of changesets as the first command.

Thanks

Boz

Update:

As per suggestion below, I tried:

```
Get-TfsItemHistory "$/path" -Version "D01/12/10~" -Recursive 
  | Where-Object {$_.WorkItems -eq $null }
```

This doesn't return any rows.  However swapping -eq for -ne does return rows (but not the ones I want obviously).

Answer (score 1):

Select object returns only the fields you request.  So you wouldn't see and object in the pipeline by the time it gets to where object if you use the where-object before select it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried as you suggested (actually, I don't the select I believe), however still now luck and no I get no rows.

Answer (score 1):

The WorkItems field is actually a collection or workitems, so null check is wrong, but counting 0 items works:

```
Get-TfsItemHistory "$/path" -Version "D01/12/10~" -Recursive 
  | Where-Object {$_.WorkItems.Count -eq 0 }
```

Also, the order of Where and Select is important, as 'rerun' user pointed out above, thanks.

Boz